# mongoose and bcrypt-nodejs not hashing and saving password

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using a bcrypt-node and mongoose to hash a users password and save that user to a mongo database. When I debug the code below it appears to be working correctly, when you log the password in the code it shows it hashed, but when you check the database it's still plain text. I'm relatively new to node and mongoose/mongodb so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot. I've tried changing calling `next();` to be `return next(user);` as suggested in another post but that didn't help. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using node version 6.9.5, mongoose 4.7.0, bcrypt-nodejs 0.0.3 and mongo 3.2.10

```
 UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {  
      var user = this;
      if (user.password != "") {
        if (this.isModified('password') || this.isNew) {
          bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
            if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
          if (err) {
            return next(err);
          }
          console.log(hash);
          user.password = hash;
          console.log(user.password);
          next();
        });
      });
    } else {
      return next();
    }
  }
  return next();
});
```

Comment: Please use consistent and meaningful indentation.

Comment: Sorry, on my screen, the indentation looks normal.

Comment: Compare to the code in the answer.

Comment: @zaph, I understand the sentiment, but perhaps that wasn't the most constructive comment. It comes across as rather condescending. Cheers.

Comment: The OP sees no indentation issue and the answer is properly indented, that was my point. It is virtually impossible to illustrate indentation in a comment.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware the answer is properly indented. I wrote it. Perhaps your point is more appropriate than I originally reacted. In fact, I didn't even really read his code. I knew exactly how to write the answer from experience, so I just did and posted it. And looking back at the original code, I can see that the indentation situation was worse than I initially thought.

Comment: The answer is fine, it is the question code that is bad. In particular: `if (err) {`
`return next(err);` `}` `bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You placed the hash function outside the genSalt() function. Also, you used some nesting and conditionals that made it hard to follow. Try the following and see how it works.

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  const user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) {
    return next();
  }
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, (error, hash) => {
      if (error) {
        return next(error);
      }
      console.log('HASH: ', hash);
      user.password = hash;
      console.log('USER.PASSWORD: ', user.password);
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

A lot more readable, right?

Comment: Thank you, that worked. When seeing your code I was able to see how bad mine looked. To much staring at my code for hours made it hard to see it formatted incorrectly. Thanks again.